# Facebook Share for websites in native dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have share&download on my site using FB.ui with the feed method for sharing. In fact, no problem occures, but strange thing happened - when I'm sharing through the fb app owner's profile [a nice native facebook popup is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLqNV.png). But when other accounts share they see [the regular new window with the url loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z90E.png).
Am I missing something? Can it be some FB profile setting or FB app setting?

Comment: are you using the same method to call the dialog for both?

Comment: yes, no code change just different facebook users.